# Sketch export multiple icons to a different file each all at once

Tags: export, sketch-app, slices

I've made these icons and i want to export them at 2X. What i do now is that i select each icon, hit export @2X and then move on to the next icon until I'm done.

Is there a way to export all my icons all at once to a different .png file each? For example, i want to select my 10 icons and end up with 10 different .png files without repeating the same task 10 times.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all of your 10 icons (because each icon has multiple components like the circle and the symbol, every icon should be a group. So you should have 10 groups) and click on *Make Exportable* on the bottom right corner. Then select *2x* for *Size* and click *Export Layers*.

Finally select the folder you want your 10 Icons to be saved in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually what I found was that my icons where named the same. So every time an icon was exported it would overwrite the previous one. So I would be left with only one icon in the end. I just changed the names and it worked fine.